# SQL : Get the Minimum Available Index (mAI)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have an SQL table field named spIndex, which may have values from 1 to n.

Say, if I have records having spIndex 1,3,4,5.
Then minimum available index is : 2

I want to find out this minimum available (mAI) index using SQL query.

```
say 
table name: account, 
field name: spIndex,
```

how can I extract the mAI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a self join:

```
select a1.spIndex + 1 mAI
from (select spIndex from account union select 0) a1 
left join account a2
on a2.spIndex = a1.spIndex + 1
where a2.spIndex is null
order by a1.spIndex limit 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=bc00baff0b6b4adbf7a75267a153cda0).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select min(spindex + 1)
from (select t.*,
             lead(spindex) over (order by spindex) as next_spindex
      from t
     ) t
where next_spindex is null or next_spindex > spindex + 1;
```

Note:  This does not return `1` if that is available.  If you need that:

```
select coalesce( (case when min(spindex) <> 1 then 1 end),
                 min(spindex) + 1
               )
from (select t.*,
             lead(spindex) over (order by spindex) as next_spindex
      from t
     ) t
where next_spindex is null or next_spindex > spindex + 1;
```